VS Code Rust LLDP Debugger - Hanging on Breakpoints
I have VS Code on an Ubuntu machine configured to debug a Rust application. When running, the debugger will stop at a breakpoint as expected.
The problem is that once it hits the breakpoint, it appears to hang. The variables won't load:

Hovering the mouse over variable names in the editor doesn't show anything, and nothing happens if I click "Step Over" or "Continue". It's just locked up.
Of note is that this does not occur everywhere in the code. It only seems to occur on code that is within a subsystem that processes incoming network requests (responds to them).
Any advice would be appreciated.
